# Hammer.js pinchin and pinch out fail in upgrade from 1.01 to 2.04

Tags: hammer.js

Yesterday I upgraded to hammer 2.04 and my pinch gestures stopped working.

As far as I can sell the syntax from v1 should still work, and in fact tap events are working, but the pinch does not.

```
    map.hammer = new Hammer(map.canvas[0]);
    map.hammer.on("pinchin", function (e) {
        log("pinchin");
    })
    map.hammer.on("tap", function (e) {
        log("tap")
    });
```

Anyideas?

Answer (score 0):

This method works.

```
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(map.canvas[0]);
    mc.add(new Hammer.Pinch());
    mc.on("pinch", function(ev) {
        log("pinch ", ev);
    });
```